# UnresolvableHost error when making HTTP request

Tags: httprequest, azure-logic-apps

I designed a logic app that at one point needs to make an HTTP request, when I tested it, it ran all the steps successfully but fails at the request and gives me the following error

> UnresolvableHostName. Http request failed with status code 'HostNotFound' and status message: 'No such host is known.'

The HTTP request code is as follows:

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "method": "GET",
        "uri": "MYEndpointGoesHere",
        "headers": {
            "x-api-key": "APIKEYGoesHere"
        }
    }
}
```

When I make this same call from postman (same Uri and key) I get a 200 and correct response, so not sure why I am getting this error from the logic app, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the issue was that I needed to use and HTTP call with azure AD via on premise gateway